# A language that can be recognised by a TM but cannot be decided by a TM?

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines

### Can a language which can be recognised by a TM but cannot be decided by a TM?

> example of a language which can be recognised by a TM but cannot be
>   decided by a TM

Would the answer be:

```
 TM={<M,w> M is a TM that accepts input string w}
```

Could I be wrong?

---

### What is the difference between decidability and recognisability?

In short, Any string that a recognized by a TM is called TM recognizable whereas any strings that is acceptable by a TM is called TM decidable.

Comment: This question should go to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question - is there a language that is recognizable by a TM but not decidable by a TM? - the answer is "yes," and the language you've given, which is the *universal language*, is an example of such a language.

For your second question - what's the difference between decidability and recognizability? - the answer you've given is on the right track, but as written as incorrect. Remember that decidability and recognizability are properites of *languages*, not *strings*. There's no such thing as a "decidable string" or a "recognizable string."

A language L is decidable if there's a TM M with the following properties: for every string w ∈ L, M accepts w, and for every string w ∉ L, M rejects w. In other words, if you don't know whether w is in L or not, you can run M on w, wait for it to give you an answer, and discover the answer.

A language L is recognizable if there's a TM M with the following properties: for every string w ∈ L, M accepts w, and for every string w ∉ L, M does not accept w (that is, either M loops on w, or M rejects w). In other words, if you are sure that w ∈ L and want to confirm this, you can run M on w, watch it accept w, and be certain that your answer was right, but if you didn't know in advance whether w is in L, you might not be able to use M to find out the answer, since M might loop on w.

Comment: So in short a decidable is a when a TM can accept or reject the language whereas the recognizable may not accept or reject but still be readable by the TM?

Comment: @SA You have to be careful with the terminology here. TMs run on individual strings. The behavior of the TM as a whole determines the language of the TM. This means that you can't "accept" or "reject" a language. You also need to define what "readable" means, because that term doesn't have a specific meaning. I like to think of decidability like this: a language is decidable if there's a mechanical procedure that will tell you the answer to any question of the form "is string w in the language?" A language is recognizable if, whenever a string is in the language, there's a way to prove it.